# Object detection/tracking

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I want to write a program in Java to have *"Object Detection and Tracking"* function, I have searched for that and found that there are libraries that can do this. Like OpenCV, if someone needs to use it in Java needs to use JavaCV wrapper..., but I did not find any good tutorials to learn how to use OpenCV and JavaCV, what we need if use these libraries. If someone knows about this, can suggest me where I can find these tutorials.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good 'quick start' tutorial here:

https://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Note that the Java libraries are simply wrappers around the C++ libraries, so once you are up and running with the Java libraries, you can find any functionality you need in the C++ tutorials